# jQuery: Multiple selectors in a single variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a function triggerd by certain classes. I tried it like that but it didn't work :(

```
var ajaxlinks = $(".ajaxlink") $(".navlinks").find('a');

ajaxlinks.click(function(e){ ... }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `,` to separate different selectors:

```
$(".ajaxlink, .navlinks").find("a");
```

Comment: The problem is that `.ajaxlink` is already a link, `.navlink` is just a wrapper with a link inside.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use jQuery selectors the same as CSS selectors. So if you need all ajaxlinks, and all a tags within .navlinks (all of them, so not just the direct children) you can use `$(".ajaxlink, .navlinks a");`